# How to get the free space of Google Drive with Google Drive API

Tags: wpf, google-drive-api

I am creating windows application with Google Drive API. In this a user can upload and download the files/folders on Google drive. So I want to show the user how much space is left on his/her Google drive. I am using service account for drive service. I search on this but could not find anything. I want exactly like if we lo-gin on G-mail account and then go to 
  https://www.google.com/settings/storage?hl=en_US
and see the left most graph showing "Total Storage". I want to have the same in my application.

Please help me on this.

Answer (score 5):

You can get the user quota information by calling the Web API :

https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/about/get

There you'll be able to find used quota and available space